# TorchServe worker dies - Message size exceed limit

Tags: pytorch, torchserve

Every once in a while a TorchServe worker dies with the following message `io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: Message size exceed limit: 16`. When I rerun the request in question, it completes with no problems. Interestingly, this error only occurs on similarity models batching enabled (see config.properties).

I have tried to solve the issue by increasing response and request size in the `config.properties`. This hasn't helped.

```
async_logging=true
max_response_size=1000000000
max_request_size=1000000000
```

Additional  information:

I am using the docker image [pytorch/torchserve:0.7.1-gpu](https://hub.docker.com/layers/pytorch/torchserve/0.7.1-gpu/images/sha256-6be7afec8dfc9e26548ddccd707a0f006ec20998a3f4eb88ca3881e8db353536?context=explore) to run a few BERT models on GPU.

Providing full TS `config.properties`:

```
load_models=all
async_logging=true
max_response_size=1000000000
max_request_size=1000000000

models={\
  "text_similarity_v1": {\
    "1.0": {\
        "defaultVersion": true,\
        "minWorkers": 1,\
        "maxWorkers": 1,\
        "batchSize": 16,\
        "maxBatchDelay": 100\
    }\
  },\
  "text_similarity_v2": {\
    "1.0": {\
        "defaultVersion": true,\
        "minWorkers": 1,\
        "maxWorkers": 1,\
        "batchSize": 16,\
        "maxBatchDelay": 100\
    }\
  },\
  "price": {\
    "1.5": {\
        "defaultVersion": true,\
        "minWorkers": 1,\
        "maxWorkers": 1,\
        "batchSize": 1,\
        "maxBatchDelay": 100\
    }\
  },\
  "categorization": {\
    "1.5": {\
        "defaultVersion": true,\
        "minWorkers": 1,\
        "maxWorkers": 1,\
        "batchSize": 1,\
        "maxBatchDelay": 100\
    }\
  },\
  "text_quality": {\
    "1.4": {\
        "defaultVersion": true,\
        "minWorkers": 1,\
        "maxWorkers": 1,\
        "batchSize": 1,\
        "maxBatchDelay": 100\
    }\
  }\
}
```

Providing full TorchServe error message:

```
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    2023-04-27T07:58:56,360 [ERROR] epollEventLoopGroup-5-4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Unknown exception
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: Message size exceed limit: 16
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    Consider increasing the 'max_response_size' in 'config.properties' to fix.
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at org.pytorch.serve.util.codec.CodecUtils.readLength(CodecUtils.java:24) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at org.pytorch.serve.util.codec.CodecUtils.readMap(CodecUtils.java:54) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at org.pytorch.serve.util.codec.ModelResponseDecoder.decode(ModelResponseDecoder.java:73) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollDomainSocketChannel$EpollDomainUnsafe.epollInReady(EpollDomainSocketChannel.java:138) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    2023-04-27T07:58:56,361 [INFO ] epollEventLoopGroup-5-4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - 9003 Worker disconnected. WORKER_MODEL_LOADED
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    2023-04-27T07:58:56,361 [ERROR] epollEventLoopGroup-5-4 org.pytorch.serve.wlm.WorkerThread - Unknown exception
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    io.netty.handler.codec.CorruptedFrameException: Message size exceed limit: 16
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    Consider increasing the 'max_response_size' in 'config.properties' to fix.
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at org.pytorch.serve.util.codec.CodecUtils.readLength(CodecUtils.java:24) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at org.pytorch.serve.util.codec.CodecUtils.readMap(CodecUtils.java:54) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at org.pytorch.serve.util.codec.ModelResponseDecoder.decode(ModelResponseDecoder.java:73) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:501) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:440) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:404) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:371) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:354) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:241) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1405) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:262) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:248) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:901) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$8.run(AbstractChannel.java:819) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:164) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:472) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:384) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[model-server.jar:?]
2023-04-27T09:58:56.368+02:00    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) [?:?]
```

UPDATE: We narrowed down the problem to batching. We are currently running all predictions with `batchSize: 1` and workers are no longer dying. Will keep you posted if we figure out how to fix the issue with batching.